# Dapper and values greater than decimal.MaxValue

Tags: c#, oracle, precision, dapper

My team has a readonly REST API that other products made by our company can use to retrieve information from our product. The API is in C# using Dapper to read from an Oracle database. Because 1) precision is important in this context, and 2) it's the type that best fits Oracle's number column type, we read values out of the database into C# `decimal` variables.

We have run into a situation where a customer is getting errors from the API because they have some bad data in their system. Normally the API handles bad data just fine, however in this case the data is a 30-digit number, which is greater than `decimal.MaxValue`. When the API tries to retrieve this value, we get a "column name is <null>" error out of Dapper, which 1) was not very helpful in tracking down the problem since it handles nulls just fine, and 2) causes the entire database read to fail.

We strongly prefer to preserve bad data that comes into the system, so that customers can see it and figure out where it's coming from (as it could indicate problems in upstream systems), so we don't want to fix the data in the database to resolve this issue. And, as mentioned, we want to stick with `decimal` to preserve precision. However, other downstream products do not necessarily need to be given this bad data (aggregating data & fixing errors in it is a major focus of our product). Is there any way we can get Dapper to succeed on this query and simply emit null in place of values that don't fit inside a `decimal`?

Comment: Create a store procedure or a view and replace the numbers that are going over Dapper capabilities with NULL and in this way you will have your functionality in place.

Comment: Or, instead of NULL, pick some number (say, `decimal.MaxValue`) to represent the overflow situation.

Comment: Can you just not use a computed field for this? Not an Oracle person, but in SQL I would use a computed field on the table and read on this one.

Comment: @TomTom Oracle queries are SQL. Do you mean SQL Server?

Comment: Yeah. I also would question the original idea that decimal is a good data type. Unless those numbers are calculated upon - they are numeric strings, not numbers. I can not imagine a scenario where the OP's posted scenario (one gets numbers that high and can safely ignore them) happens.

Comment: @TomTom A *valid* value for that field would be less than 100. However, we don't do any arithmetic with these numbers (in the API where they're being read out as a decimal), and the difference between 14.73 and 14.729999999815 can be relevant, so we prefer to stick with decimal for the API. However, we also accept data from upstream systems, and those can have errors that cause them to simply push out junk data (such as the 30-digit number in this case).

Comment: Jish, that is an awful environment there. Not blaming you - if upstream craps out, that is what you deal with.

Comment: Still a bit strange. If a system can produce and push junk to your api - it can as well push a number outside oracle's NUMBER type limits, which will fail. So you accept some junk but not the other. Not to mention it can be junk even if it's inside the range.

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you could add a virtual column to the table:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD (
  your_column_safe GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
    CASE
    WHEN your_column
         BETWEEN -79228162514264337593543950335 -- .Net decimal.MinValue
         AND     +79228162514264337593543950335 -- .Net decimal.MaxValue
    THEN your_column
    ELSE NULL
    END
  )
);
```

Then, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( your_column NUMBER );

INSERT INTO table_name (your_column)
SELECT 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT -POWER(2,96) + 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT +POWER(2,96) - 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT -POWER(2,96) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT +POWER(2,96) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT -1e31 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT +1e31 FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

Outputs:

> | YOUR_COLUMN | YOUR_COLUMN_SAFE |
> | --- | --- |
> | 0 | 0 |
> | -79228162514264337593543950335 | -79228162514264337593543950335 |
> | 79228162514264337593543950335 | 79228162514264337593543950335 |
> | -79228162514264337593543950336 | *<null>* |
> | 79228162514264337593543950336 | *<null>* |
> | -10000000000000000000000000000000 | *<null>* |
> | 10000000000000000000000000000000 | *<null>* |

Then change dapper to read from the virtual column rather than the actual column.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=13c45c39d4f769beb361e567efb4a1df)*

Comment: I'm much more knowledgeable about coding than about databases so my first inclination is usually to look for a code solution, but your answer prompted me to think about potential approaches in Oracle. What would you say are the pros/cons of a virtual column versus just using `(case when column > decimal_max or column < decimal_min then null else column end) as column_safe` in select statements?

Comment: @ObliviousSage It depends on how Dapper handles it. It may be impractical if you have to use it in lots of locations and there are many developers who would need to remember to always use that code. However, if there is only a single location where you need to use the `CASE` statement then it may be fine. I use Django as an ORM rather than Dapper; you would need ask a Dapper expert for a more nuanced view.